# Android - Best Practice for Downloading Medium - Large Files Quickly

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask

I need to download a few large zip files into my application (each approx 25mb) however it seems quite slow (5 minutes +) and when we test the same files being downloaded on an iPad it's downloading several times faster. I've considered using Volley, however it seems asynctask is the best for large files (from what I've read).

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how I might be able to download/write these files faster?

My current implementation is show below:

### My AsyncTaskExample:

```
@Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
     InputStream input = null;
     OutputStream output = null;
     HttpURLConnection connection = null;
     try {
         URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
         connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         connection.connect();

         // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
         // instead of the file
         if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                     + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
         }

         // this will be useful to display download percentage
         // might be -1: server did not report the length
         int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

         // download the file
         input = connection.getInputStream();
         output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

         byte data[] = new byte[1024];
         long total = 0;
         int count;
         while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
             // allow canceling with back button
             if (isCancelled()) {
                 input.close();
                 return null;
             }
             total += count;
             // publishing the progress....
             if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                 publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
             output.write(data, 0, count);
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         return e.toString();
     } finally {
         try {
             if (output != null)
                 output.close();
             if (input != null)
                 input.close();
         } catch (IOException ignored) {
         }

         if (connection != null)
             connection.disconnect();
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) should be used only for relatively short background processes (i.e. processes that last a few seconds). From the docs:

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and
>   [FutureTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).

For long operations you should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use.